# square root function on Python using Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I'm just starting out using both Python under Spyder.  I was about to do a simple square root calculation.  I see that in Python, you need to do an "import math".  I did that in Spyder and got an error: 'math' imported but unused.  I tried using sqrt() but that threw an error.  There's something fundamental I'm missing here.  I did a bunch of searching and still have not been able to figure this issue out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!
clem

Comment: Instead of making us guess, show us the code you wrote that isn’t working with any error messages you are receiving. You should “start out“ with a basic python tutorial.

Comment: HI Mark,  Thanks.  Yeah, did that.  Watched an hour long basic tutorial.  Then when I couldn't get the sqrt function to work, searched and read some help files and tried some of it and only posted this when I exhausted those attempts.  So I did try.  Sorry I didn't mention that.  I didn't want to go through everything I tried but guess I should have.

Comment: But still, [edit] the question with the code you tried so we can help you understand where you went wrong instead of guessing.  Read the [mcve] guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 3 options.

1:

```
import math

n = 5

print(math.sqrt(n))
```

2:

```
from math import sqrt

n = 5

print(sqrt(n))
```

3:

```
n = 5

print(n ** 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

print(math.sqrt(25))
```

Or

```
from math import sqrt

print(sqrt(25))
```

And oh! for good measure:

```
import math

def sqrt(n):
    return "I am not the function you're looking for"

print(math.sqrt(25))
print(sqrt(25))  # see what happened here?
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry all -- rookie move!  I thought the variable containing a number inherited the math methods - and I thought I saw this in some of the stuff that I read!  So I was trying
z = 10
print( z.sqrt )

I got it now!  I started in with MS basic, moved to Fortran, some java, some javascript, some others.  I'm trying to do a little math -- writing a little thing that calculate the determinant of a 2x2 matrix formed by a couple of vectors (yeah, i know -- there's prob a Det method).  I got the code work in another language but just tried it in Python as a learning task.  Apologies for the dumb question but appreciate you all giving me a hand.